# CASE inside SELECT..FOR XML to create conditional element

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

How do/can I use `CASE` inside `SELECT..FOR XML`?

If this is not possible, is there any way to determine desired element name and put a value in it. Logic would be `if amount < 0 then create <PostClassDt> element else <PostClassCr>`. Amounts are taken from same table.

Something like this :

```
<Document>
  <TxnList>
     <Txn>
        <Amt Curr="EUR">-123.45</Amt>
        <PostClassDt>debit</PostClassDt>
      </Txn>
      <Txn>
        <Amt Curr="USD">456.78</Amt>
        <PostClassCr>return</PostClassCr>
    </Txn>
    </TxnList>
</Document>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create two columns, and make the ones you don't want `NULL`, then `NULL` elements don't create nodes, e.g.

```
SELECT  [Amt/@Curr] = t.Curr,
        t.Amt, 
        PostClassDt = CASE WHEN Amt < 0 THEN 'debit' END,
        PostClassCr = CASE WHEN Amt >= 0 THEN 'return' END
FROM    (VALUES 
            ('EUR', -123.45),
            ('USD', 456.78)
        ) t (Curr, Amt)
FOR XML PATH('Txn'), ROOT('TxnList');
```

This gives:

```
<TxnList>
  <Txn>
    <Amt Curr="EUR">-123.45</Amt>
    <PostClassDt>debit</PostClassDt>
  </Txn>
  <Txn>
    <Amt Curr="USD">456.78</Amt>
    <PostClassCr>return</PostClassCr>
  </Txn>
</TxnList>
```

Comment: Great! Just a tiny hint: If `Amt=0` nothing would be created. One option should be `>=` or `<=`...